# Python 3.6 - is there a condition that can behave like otherwise?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

My example (list a and b are always the same size):

```
a = ['12','12','12','12','12','23','24','24','31','31']
b = ['1','2','2','2','2','2','5','5','5','5']
c = a, b
```

Here is my code which needs something like an otherwise condition, the c[0] is so that the code only looks through list a rather than both lists and prints out the result of list a and b that fit the condition. **The else condition in this code is wrong and I cant think of an alternative**:

```
d = list(zip(*[(ai,bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if c[0].count(ai) == 5 else 2]))

e = list(zip(*[(ai,bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if c[0].count(ai) == 7 else 2]))
```

Is it possible to change the condition so that it prints only counts of 5 if there are more than 2 counts in my example? Or that it prints only counts of 2 if 7 is the initial count but there are none detected?

My desired outcome:

```
d = [('12','12','12','12','12',), ('1','2','2','2','2')]

e = [('24','24','31','31'), ('5','5','5','5')]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why the `c[0].count(...)` when you just could do `a.count(...)`?

Comment: Also note that calling `count()` repeatedly is *expensive*. Create a `Counter()` first and use that object instea.

Comment: Hi I mean that the code will look through list a and count if there are 5 repeating numbers. If there are then it will print out the 5 numbers. In another case I want it see if there are 7 repeating numbers. If there are then it will print out the 7 numbers however if there aren't 7, then it will print out only numbers with 2 counts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it possible to see an example of your explanation?

Comment: I think I know what you want to do, but that's not how list comprehensions work. You are making a single decision *up front*, before filtering. If there is an element that appears 5 times exactly, then select those, otherwise select elements that appear 2 times. Count first, then select one or the other subset to filter on.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but an example would be great to fully understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to count your elements **first**, then decide which ones you are selecting. Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count elements efficiently, so you can then decide what elements are to be picked:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(a)
has_5 = any(c == 5 for c in counts.values())
has_7 = any(c == 7 for c in counts.values())
```

Now you know if there is an element that appears 5 times, and if there is an element that appears 7 times. You can now filter those elements by how many times they appear, without re-counting each iteration. Make your pick *first*, so you don't have to complicate the `if` logic:

```
desired_count = 5 if has_5 else 2
d = list(zip(*[(ai,bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if counts[ai] == desired_count]))

desired_count = 7 if has_7 else 2
e = list(zip(*[(ai,bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if counts[ai] == desired_count]))
```

So *if* there is an element that appears 5 times, filter on those, otherwise filter on elements that only appear twice.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = ['12','12','12','12','12','23','24','24','31','31']
>>> b = ['1','2','2','2','2','2','5','5','5','5']
>>> counts = Counter(a)
>>> has_5 = any(c == 5 for c in counts.values())
>>> has_7 = any(c == 7 for c in counts.values())
>>> desired_count = 5 if has_5 else 2
>>> list(zip(*[(ai,bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if counts[ai] == desired_count]))
[('12', '12', '12', '12', '12'), ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2')]
>>> desired_count = 7 if has_7 else 2
>>> list(zip(*[(ai,bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if counts[ai] == desired_count]))
[('24', '24', '31', '31'), ('5', '5', '5', '5')]
```

Comment: thank you for the help and explanation, it is good alternative!

Comment: adding further conditions to that, could use elif before the else condition?

Comment: @F.Lee: no, a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) doesn't have an `elif` option. Just chain them, or expand to using a full `if .. elif .. else` statement.

Comment: When you mean chain them, do you mean like 'if has_7 else 5 else 2' ?

Comment: @F.Lee: the part before the `if` and after the `else` are themselves expressions, so you can put another conditional expression there `7 if has_7 else (5 if has_5 else 2)`.